# Feasible dotnet for a project which call or called by multiple other dotnet project

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am having a stateful service which is using target framework as "netcoreapp3.1". And This service will be calling Some test projects and other dependencies. We need to add these projects and dependencies as reference. Most of them uses net472 framework. And some of them  use dotnet core 3.1. I added 2 test projects here in csproj as ProjectReference. They both have net472 framework. Due to one of them, The pipeline run is failing. If i remove the reference of one, The pipeline run got succeed.

Note: This stateful service is getting called from some other service which is also uses dotnet core.

I am new to c#, visual studio and dotnet libraries. I tired changing the framework of stateful service as dotnet standard. But that got failed as it's calling some of the services which use dotnet core. I didn't get that What library will fix this? Or i need to change the architecture.

Comment: I don't see an **information security** problem here, i.e. off-topic.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich for migrating this here.

Comment: Since you've narrowed it down to one project, I'd try migrating that one to 3.1 core.  (then eventually go about migrating the rest so you can get away from all .net4.x framework dependencies... core should include support for all of them...)

Comment: Pls use [.Net_Portability_Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) to check if some libraries are incompatible.

Comment: In addition, it should be noted that .net core can be cross-platform. If you add a reference to the .net framework project, it will not work under linux.

Comment: @pcalkins I narrowed down to one because it was not working for others. We can't migrate the .net4.x framework dependencies as it's own by some other team. It means, I need to migrate my service from .net core to .net4.x framework? There is no other way....

Comment: I migrated my service from .netcore to .net6.x framework.